# Authentication between proxy server and main server

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

**Authentication between proxy server and main server**

I had build proxy server in nodejs and i had also build three other main server. request goes from proxy server to other three server according to routes. i want to make communication between proxy server and other server secure. so i am planning to use HTTPS for server communication. but, i also want to perform server level authentication. i want to perform token based authentication between servers. so how can i perform token based authentication and where can i store my token on server.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
if($key != $key1)
```

to

```
if($key != $key1 && !empty($value) && !empty($value1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is explained in in the error message, i.e. you're calling a function called `getTitle()` on a string `$value` and `$value1`.

In your inner and outer `foreach` loops you're starting with a variable called `$json` ~ which presumably contains JSON of the form:

```json
{"aKey": "a text item", "bKey": "b text item", "cKey": "c text item", "dKey": "d text item", "eKey": "e text item", "fKey": "f text item", "gKey": "g text item"}
```

As explained in the PHP docs about [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) the form:

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
```

is placing the key in `$key` (so "aKey") and a string in `$value` (so "a text item").

Strings are not objects and do not have a method called `getTitle()`